# source_sink `appl' does not exist

Tags: eclipse, prolog, swi-prolog

I have this line in a project (the project was not created by me, but it is a university project)

```
:- [appl], assert(max_id(333)).
```

when i try to compile in eclipse with the [ProDT plugin](http://prodevtools.sourceforge.net/) it gives me this error:

```
    source_sink `appl' does not exist
```

What does the line of code mean? And what about the error now?

Comment: You may want to peruse this: [SWI Prolog - Getting started quickly](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=quickstart) or [SICStus Prolog - How to run](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/3.7.1/html/sicstus_4.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a `appl.pl` file does exists in the project, most likely your current directory is not the directory of the file. Either use a full path to load the file (e.g. `['/full/path/to/appl']`) or change directory first to the directory of the file (using the `cd/1` predicate; e.g. `cd('/some/path/'), [appl]`).

To find the current directory, use the `pwd/0` predicate:

```
?- pwd.
```

Comment: I don't know if is a file, in the project folder there's no file with this name.
:- [ something ] what does mean?

Comment: The `[file]` is a top-level interpreter shortcut to compile and load a Prolog file.